# webrtc peer to peer video chat behind NAT without STUN server

Tags: webrtc, nat, stun

Can I code a website which allows p2p video calls for peers behind NATs without relaying the video data myself as a 3rd party server (since it is expensive)

my network knowledge says it's impossible but this is not emphasized in any docs I've been reading, so simple yes/no answer to this question please.

and I assume most of the computers people use are behind NATs, so they are not outliers but the norm.

Answer (score 1):

Not impossible. Definitely possible, but not 100% reliable.

[WebRTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC) does support peer to peer video conferencing using [STUN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STUN) instead of [TURN relays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traversal_Using_Relays_around_NAT).

Bare minimum for establishing a WebRTC session:

1. At least a STUN server for clients to self-discover their own IP:port mappings
2. Your own web service for clients to exchange SDP data generated by WebRTC APIs.

The TURN server is a superset to STUN that supports relay data as well. While you aren't required to have it, clients that are behind "symmetric NAT" or any NAT configuration where the port mapping can not be predicted will have difficulty connecting to other endpoints.